# pandas drop duplicate row value from a specific column

Tags: pandas

I want to remove the duplicate row value from a specific column - in this case the column name is "number".

Before:

```
        number qty status
    0    10      2    go
    1    10      5    nogo
    2    4       6    yes
    3    3       1    no
    4    2       7    go
    5    5       2    nah
    6    5       6    go
    7    5       3    nogo
    8    1       10   yes
    9    1       10   go 
    10   5       2    nah
```

After:

```
        number qty status
    0    10      2    go
                 5    nogo
    1    4       6    yes
    2    3       1    no
    3    2       7    go
    4    5       2    nah
                 6    go
                 3    nogo
    5    1       10   yes
                 10   go 
    6    5       2    nah
```

Comment: When you say "drop" you mean "make NaN" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible replace values to empty string or NaNs by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) by new Series `a` created by comparing column with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed column with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
a = df['number'].ne(df['number'].shift()).cumsum()
#for replace ''
df['number'] =  df['number'].mask(a.duplicated(), '')
#for replace NaNs
#df['number'] =  df['number'].mask(a.duplicated())
print (df)
   number  qty status
0      10    2     go
1            5   nogo
2       4    6    yes
3       3    1     no
4       2    7     go
5       5    2    nah
6            6     go
7            3   nogo
8       1   10    yes
9           10     go
10      5    2    nah
```

Detail:

```
a = df['number'].ne(df['number'].shift()).cumsum()
print (a)
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     5
7     5
8     6
9     6
10    7
Name: number, dtype: int32
```